# Blackberry - Facebook Connect on web

Tags: facebook, blackberry

I have a mobile microsite I'm building and currently I can't get facebook connect to work with blackberry.  I get the error "An error occured with ***_*__*_***. Please try again later."

I've tested this on every other device I can get my hands on and only blackberry gives me issues.

here is the code i'm using to load the app.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // App ID
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', handleStatusChange);
};

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
</script>

<script>
function loginUser() {    
 FB.login(function(response) { }, {scope:'email'});     
 }
</script>
<script>
function handleResponseChange(response) {
  document.body.className = response.authResponse ? 'connected' : 'not_connected';
  if (response.authResponse) {
    console.log(response);
    updateUserInfo(response);
  }
}
</script>


<script>
function updateUserInfo(response) {
 FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  window.location.href='home.php';
 });
}
</script>


<div id="login"><p><button id="fblogin" onClick="loginUser();"></button></p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the OAuth changes were breaking it.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/416132398431057?browse=search_4fd05d1660f9a9c22137268